# OOP Javascript vs object literal

Tags: javascript, oop

I find myself rarely will use OOP, I mean like this

```
function Person(name){
return this.name = name;
}

Person.prototype.dateOfBirth = function(){
//some stuff here
}

var John = new Person('John');
console.log(John.dateOfBirth);
```

Maybe I'm not building a framework or whatever but sometime I like to group my method using object literal instead like

```
    var John = {
    name:'John',
    dateOfBirth: function(){
    // return etc
    }
    }

John.dateOfBirth();
```

Maybe because JS is a client side language so OOP is quite redundant, can u guys share about ur OOP experience using JS? I learned the basic like prototypical inheritance and advance objects of JS but I haven't find any use case for it.

Comment: "Maybe because JS is a client side language so OOP is quite redundant". Why do you think so?

Comment: Are you referring to object literals and construction functions?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Using prototypes is useful for many objects of the same class, mainly because each method for the objects only need to be defined once. Using the literal method makes duplicates methods other than sharing a single one. So it can be more efficient and use less memory in those situations, although other than that there isn't much of a difference.

Comment: @RosdiKasim at Programmers this would probably be closed, either as **[too broad](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**, or as a duplicate of [Are there any OO-principles that are practically applicable for Javascript?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/180588/31260)

Answer (score 1):

Check out the revealing module pattern, in which you have control over what's exposed and what's not. I think it gives the public/privacy control that one wish for in OOP.

[This blog post is a good example](https://carldanley.com/js-revealing-module-pattern/)

```
var Person = (function() {

  var name = "default";

  function dateOfBirth() {
    privateBirthCalculation(); //can only be invoked inside of the scope
    console.log( 'dateOfBirth' );
  }

  function privateBirthCalculation() {
    console.log( 'my private method' );
  }

  // explicitly return public methods and properties when this object is instantiated
  return {
    dateOfBirth : dateOfBirth,
    name: name
  };

})();
```

Comment: why do u need public and private function in JavaScript?

Comment: Read this, http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#detailmodule (scroll down to 'The Module Pattern')